# Regular expression to match group of letters on either side of a special character

Tags: regex, google-sheets, gs-vlookup

In a Google Spreadsheet I have cells with strings like "FOO@BAR" what is the best way to write a REGEXREPLACE to match the three letters on either side?

So for example if A1 contained "FOO@BAR" and the VLOOKUP returned "FOO"

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,""&VLOOKUP(B2,'Lookup Table'!A:B,2,FALSE)&"[^a-zA-Z0-9]","")
```

would return "BAR" but would not work if the VLOOKUP had found "BAR"

Comment: Is there any reason `/(\w{3})@/` and `/@(\w{3})/` won't work?

Comment: I want to combine is into a single regex for a REGEXREPLACE that will match for the three letters on either side of the "@" symbol

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"@*?"&VLOOKUP(B2,'Lookup Table'!A:B,2,FALSE)&"*@?","")
```

to match an "@" symbol on either side. Not sure if that is the best solution or not.

Answer (score 0):

can you just regexreplace that single character @ symbol?

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A5,"@","")
```